# Is there a way to have a object type of your choice (i.e. LinkedEdge) hash as part of a 'union.set()' processing?

Tags: python

I have the following code and it works until it gets to the 'union.set()' part. It says, "unhashable type: 'LinkedEdge' " .  I am not sure why this is the case since I have looked at other sources on the web and in reference books to know that the 'g.addVertex()' method and the 'g.addEdge()' method as well as the arguments being passed should lead correctly to an output like this:

5 Vertices: A C B E D

5 Edges: A>B:3 A>C:2 B>D:1 C>D:1 D>E:2

```
class LinkedEdge(object):

    def __init__(self, fromVertex, toVertex, weight = None):
        self._vertex1 = fromVertex
        self._vertex2 = toVertex
        self._weight = weight
        self._mark = False

    def clearMark(self):
        self._mark = False

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if self is other: return True
        if type(self) != type(other):
            return False

        return self._vertex1 == other._vertex1 and self._vertex2 == other._vertex2

    def getOtherVertex(self,    thisVertex):

        if thisVertex == None or thisVertex == self._vertex2:
            return self._vertex1
        else:
            return self._vertex2

    def getToVertex(self):
        return self._vertex2

    def getWeight(self):
        return self._weight

    def isMarked(self):
        return self._mark

    def setMark(self):
        self._mark = True

    def setWeight(self, weight):
        self._weight = weight

    def __str__(self):

        return str(self._vertex1) + ">" +  str(self._vertex2) + ":" +  str(self._weight)


class LinkedVertex(object):

    def __init__(self, label):
        self._label = label
        self._edgeList = []
        self._mark = False

    def clearMark(self):
        self._mark = False;

    def getLabel(self):
        return self._label

    def isMarked(self):
        return self._mark

    def setLabel(self, label, g):
        g._vertices.pop(self._label, None)
        g._vertices[label] = self
        self._label = label

    def setMark(self):
        self._mark = True

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self._label)


    def addEdgeTo(self, toVertex, weight):
        edge = LinkedEdge(self, toVertex, weight)
        self._edgeList.append(edge)

    def getEdgeTo(self, toVertex):
        edge = LinkedEdge(self, toVertex)
        try:
            return self._edgeList[self._edgeList.index(edge)] 
        except:
            return None

    def incidentEdges(self):
        return iter(self._edgeList)

    def neighboringVertices(self):
        vertices = []
        for edge in self._edgeList:
            vertices.append(edge.getOtherVertex(self))
        return iter(vertices)

    def removeEdgeTo(self, toVertex): 
        edge = LinkedEdge(self, toVertex) 
        if edge in self._edgeList:
            self._edgeList.remove(edge)
            return True
        else:
            return False

class LinkedDirectedGraph(object):

    def __init__(self, collection = None): 
        self._vertexCount = 0 
        self._edgeCount = 0 
        self._vertices = {}
        if collection != None:
            for label in collection:
                self.addVertex(label)

    # Methods for clearing, marks, sizes, string rep

    def clear(self):
        self._vertexCount = 0
        self._edgeCount = 0
        self._vertices = {}

    def clearEdgeMarks(self):
        for edge in self.edges():
            edge.clearMark()

    def clearVertexMarks(self):
        for vertex in self.vertices():
            vertex.clearMark()

    def isEmpty(self):
        return self._vertexCount == 0;

    def sizeEdges(self):

        return self._edgeCount

    def sizeVertices(self):
        return self._vertexCount

    def __str__(self):
        result = str(self.sizeVertices()) + " Vertices: "
        for vertex in self._vertices:
            result += " " + str(vertex)
        result += "\n";
        result += str(self.sizeEdges()) + " Edges: "
        for edge in self.edges():
            result += " " + str(edge)
        return result

    def addVertex(self, label):
        self._vertices[label] = LinkedVertex(label)
        self._vertexCount += 1

    def containsVertex (self, label):
        return label in self._vertices

    def getVertex(self, label):
        return self._vertices[label]

    def removeVertex(self,  label):
        removedVertex = self._vertices.pop(label, None)
        if removedVertex is None:
            return False

        # Examine all vertices
        for vertex in self.vertices():
            if vertex.removeEdgeTo(removedVertex):
                self._edgeCount -= 1
        self._vertexCount -= 1
        return True

    def addEdge(self, fromLabel, toLabel, weight):

        fromVertex = self.getVertex(fromLabel) 
        toVertex = self.getVertex(toLabel) 
        fromVertex.addEdgeTo(toVertex, weight) 
        self._edgeCount += 1

    def containsEdge(self, fromLabel, toLabel):
        return self.getEdge(fromLabel, toLabel) != None

    def getEdge(self, fromLabel, toLabel): 
        fromVertex = self._vertices[fromLabel] 
        toVertex = self._vertices[toLabel]
        return fromVertex.getEdgeTo(toVertex)

    def removeEdge (self, fromLabel, toLabel):
        fromVertex = self.getVertex(fromLabel) 
        toVertex = self.getVertex(toLabel) 
        edgeRemovedFlg = fromVertex.removeEdgeTo(toVertex) 
        if edgeRemovedFlg:
            self._edgeCount -= 1
        return edgeRemovedFlg

    # Iterators

    def edges(self):
        result = set()

        for vertex in self.vertices(): 
            edges = vertex.incidentEdges() 
            result = result.union(set(edges))
        return iter(result)

    def vertices(self):
        return iter(self._vertices.values())

    def incidentEdges(self, label):
        return self._vertices[label].incidentEdges()

    def neighboringVertices(self, label):
        return self._vertices[label].neighboringVertices


g = LinkedDirectedGraph()
# Insert vertices
g.addVertex("John")
g.addVertex("Sam")
g.addVertex("Megan")
g.addVertex("Jennifer")
g.addVertex("Rick")
# Insert weighted edges
g.addEdge("John", "Sam", 3)
g.addEdge("John", "Megan", 2)
g.addEdge("Sam", "Jennifer", 1)
g.addEdge("Megan", "Jennifer", 1)
g.addEdge("Jennifer", "Rick", 2)
print(g)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you override `__eq__`, then Python intentionally makes your class unhashable, since there is no longer a guarantee that the default hashing algorithm (based on the object's location in memory) is compatible with your `__eq__` algorithm. "Compatible" here just means that equal objects must have equal hashes. By default, nothing is equal, so when you make some things equal using an `__eq__` method, you impose a requirement on what a proper hash function must do.

If you want a custom class with a custom `__eq__` method to be hashable, you must implement a `__hash__` method yourself.

It could be as simple as being based on the hash of the corresponding tuple:

```py
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((type(self), self._vertex1, self._vertex2))
```

The Python docs explain this [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__).

Comment: Yay, it works perfectly! <3 <3 <3